# "Tex capacity exceeded." with beamer

Tags: beamer, pdftex

I use MikTex 2.9 and am compiling a `beamer` presentation. I have 100+ pages. The file compiles if I comment out about half of the frames. I managed one presentation by compiling the two halves one after the other and combining the two pdfs later. This, however, is a big headache to manage outlines and reference.

The exact message is:

```
Tex capacity exceeded. sorry. [input stack size = 5000].
```

Increasing the stack size to 50000 is to no avail. Can that be due to large number of frames, or since the outline frame cannot hold all the topics. I simply could  not have any clue. Any ideas??

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! That error is usually produced by a wrong definition, such as `\renewcommand{\foo}{something \foo}` trying to redefine a command in terms of itself.

Comment: @egreg: Using `\foo` after your redefinition will overflow the main memory. To overflow the input stack it must be the other way round: `\renewcommand{\foo}{\foo something}`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yes, thank you. The point is that the OP should know that redefining a command in terms of itself can't be done in a naïve way.

Comment: Thank you so much. I indeed had a stray redefinition of at two places:

Comment: @agautam Did that resolve the issue, then?  If so, we'll probably close this as "too localised" simply to ensure that open questions really are open.

Comment: Closed for now. Feel free to flag it for reopening if the issue is not solved.